# How to remove every line starting with specific string from log file?

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to remove every line starting with [null from a log file (including the open bracket).

```
sed -n '/^[null/p' filename.log
```

is giving me an error.

any ideas ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '/\[null/{next} 1' filename.log
```

Or, negate the match with `awk`

```
awk '!/\[null/' filename.log    # Thanks George Vasiliou!
```

Or, reverse the sense you have with `sed` and print as a default but delete the pattern with a match:

```
sed '/\[null/d' filename.log
```

Or, negated print on no print `sed` (which is kinda confusing...)

```
sed -n '/\[null/!p' filename.log
```

And `grep`:

```
grep -v '\[null' filename.log
```

With any regex tool, the `[` is a regex metacharacter and needs to be escaped to be the literal version of that.

Comment: Golfing: `awk '!/^\[null/'`

Comment: You forgot `grep`.

Comment: Thanks guys, that worked perfectly! Really appreciate it.